# Agent Presentation(Color) Change Dynamically

Tags: anylogic

How could I change the agent presentation dynamically? For example, I have a collection in main type HashMap<String, ArrayList>, when the model starts the collection is populated; ArrayList represents the agent "Facility" index

I want to animate the agent Facility based on the HashMap<String, ArrayList> it belongs to (this is supposed to be changed dynamically e.g. when the model starts or a new event is triggered)

so far I can set a static animation by specifying the following code in the Facility agent

```
main.deliveryData.get("0").contains(this.getIndex());
```

[image: see modelsnapshot]
How could I iterate over the collection to set up the color of the agent presentation dynamically?

any tips/help?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly some notes:

1. `getIndex()` is very inefficient as you will see from the java doc and especially if you plan to use it in some animation piece it will be very costly for your model performance.

[image]

It is better to store the index of the agent as a parameter or variable, upon creation and then use that.

2. Always use a LinkedHashMap instead of a HashMap since the latter does not guarantee the order of the elements, unless you really know what you are doing. Since the order is not guaranteed if you use a HashMap in model logic the model results will not be reproducible.  In your specific case this might not be an issue.
3. Calling `.contains()` on ArrayList is inefficient, I would suggest to rather use a Set which is very effective on checking if an element is inside the collection.

Your variable can thus be
`deliveryData = new LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashSet<Facility>>()`

But an easier way to change color of the agent is to simply change it when it needs to change using

[image]

or to only change the color dynamically - but this will come at a small performance cost as it will be evaluated every single time the canvas is redrawn or updated. You can use a ternary operator as per the example below

[image]